# React Multilenguaje

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, idioms, i18next

Does React and the i18next package support languages ​​like Catalan, Basque, Galician, Valencian, etc?

I use:

import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";
import i18next from "i18next";

But i don't know if this package support others idioms:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Supports all CLDR standard: eg. Catalan: https://unicode-org.github.io/cldr-staging/charts/latest/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html#ca

Comment: regarding language codes: https://www.i18next.com/how-to/faq#how-should-the-language-codes-be-formatted